# Не запускается редактор Atom

Tags: linux, atom

Установил редактор Atom, вообще не запускается в чем может быть проблема 
Запуск в терминале выдает ошибку: 
Отказано в доступе
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key

Comment: Покажите как вы запускаете в терминале.

Comment: Перед запуском в терминале дайте команду xhost +

Comment: набираю atom....

Comment: А если в терминале сначала ввести `export XAUTHORITY=/home/YOUR-USER-NAME/.Xauthority` и после этого попробовать запустить? Вместо YOUR-USER-NAME ваше имя пользователя, разумеется.

Comment: @Oxyd хорошо я попробую и отпишусь. Спасибо!